# Selecting the list just after a span in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I am select some data from a content which is hidden on the page. I need to select a list and then display it in a div called 'mydiv'

The hidden content resembles the following structure:

```
<h2><span class="abc" id="M"> M </span></h2>
<ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</ul>
<h2><span class="abc" id="N"> N </span></h2>
<ul>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to append the following content in mydiv:

```
M
 Content
 Content
N
 Content
 Content
```

The following is the Jquery code which is working:

```
$(".abc").each(function() {
$( this ).appendTo( "#mydiv" );
$("#mydiv").append('<br />');
});
```

The above code can display M an N right now. I am unable to find out how can I display the list too.

What I tried was:

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
$("id + ul").children().each(function(){
   //No Idea what to write
});
```

Can someone please help me with this code?
Thanks

Comment: I think correct answer would be to use $.toggle() method http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Here You can able to select <li> content and selected <li> content you needs to display div 'mydiv', is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly

```
$(".abc").each(function() {
 $(this).parent().next('ul').show().appendTo("#mydiv");
 $("#mydiv").append('<br />');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking after.

```
$(".abc").each(function() {
```

denotes the current "span" level. So in order to move forward to next `<li>` you need to use

```
$(this).parent().next().children()
```

Here is the complete code. And the [demo example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jpc3J/).

```
$(".abc").each(function() {
    $("#mydiv").append($(this).text());
    $(this).parent().next().children().each(function(){
        $("#mydiv").append('<br/>');
        $("#mydiv").append($(this).text());
    });
    $("#mydiv").append('<br/>');
});
```